# How to stop CountDownTimer from counting when user opens the next fragment?

Tags: android, android-progressbar, androidx

I have a CountDownTimer which starts counting down from 17 seconds to 0 when a user comes to this fragment. There should be now two options:

1. The user clicks on a button before the countdown gets to 0 and the button opens the next fragment
2. The countdown gets to 0 and opens automatically the next fragment

This is the desired outcome I want to have but I couldn't find a way to achieve this. How can I stop the countdown from counting when the user clicks on a button? I tried with `progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);`but the countdown still counts down. Any help is much appreciated!

Here is my code:

```
public View onCreateView (@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        ...

        // Opens the next fragment after clicking on the Ok button
        btnOkFrag1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                stopCountdownTimer();
                ((GameActivity)getActivity()).setViewPager(2);

            }
        });

        return view;
    }

// Countdown 17 seconds

    int i = 0;

    private void startCountdownTimer() {

        progressBar.setProgress(i);

        final int totalMsecs = 17 * 1000; // 17 seconds in milli seconds
        int callInterval = 100;

        /** CountDownTimer */
        new CountDownTimer(totalMsecs, callInterval) {

            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

                int secondsRemaining = (int) millisUntilFinished / 1000;

                float fraction = millisUntilFinished / (float) totalMsecs;

                // progress bar is based on scale of 1 to 10.000;
                progressBar.setProgress((int) (fraction * 10000));
            }

            public void onFinish() {

                stopCountdownTimer();
                ((GameActivity)getActivity()).setViewPager(2);
                // TODO: 2019-10-18 Open next fragment when the countdown is finished. If user clicks ok button before finish, stop countdown.

            }
        }.start();
    }

    private void stopCountdownTimer(){
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
```

Comment: Keep the instance of created CountDownTimer, and call `timer.cancel();`

Comment: How do I keep the instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can assign your CountDownTimer (as Ikazuchi said in the comment) to a variable like so:

```
  CountDownTimer countDown =  new CountDownTimer(totalMsecs, callInterval) {...
```

Then in the onClick method assigned to the button you can call

```
countDown.cancel()
```